# Python getting clear class names in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup and I have this bit of code :

```
<div class="tomato"></div>
```

And when I do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(div.get('class'))
```

I get `[u'tomato']`. Is there any way to change this code to get only "tomato" without all the other characters?

I also have a few divs that have multiple classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python string prints as \[u'String'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring)

Comment: It's possible for a `div` to have [multiple `class` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884523/can-a-div-have-multiple-classes-twitter-bootstrap), so it's returning a list of class names. What would you want it to print if there were 2 classes?

Comment: So use `classes = div.get('class', [])` and `print u' '.join(classes)` to print all classes on a div.

Comment: @PeterWood i said it can have multiple classes because if it does it will display [u'something',u'something',u'something']

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks so much man! could you explain what the commands do please?

Comment: @ChorMay: The `class` attribute returns a *list* of unicode strings. I gave `get()` a second argument to return an empty list instead of the default `None` if the attribute is missing. `unicode.join()`, like `str.join()`, takes a sequence and joins the elements into a single string, here using a space.

Comment: `div.find_all('div', {'class': 'tomato'})` would also work. Which, afaik, basically tests `if 'tomato' in div.get('class')`.